# Angularjs single html5mode pagerefresh 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, tomcat7

I'm trying to remove the #! from the URL using html5mode. I have added these `<base href="/app/"> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

When I'm refreshing the url `http://localhost:8080/app/page` I'm getting a 404 error.

I'm using tomcat7 server.

Any possible solution?

Comment: the base href would need to be the base href of the server, so it would need to be set to `http://localhost:8080/app/`

Comment: Nope. Not working

Comment: do you still get a 404? what does the console say?

Comment: Nothing in the console. The page itself is not loading   HTTP Status 404 - /app/page

type Status report

message /app/page

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: in which case, you're probably trying to load files which arent where you think they are

Comment: It is loading file like this for the firsttime "http://localhost:8080/app/templates/page.html" When I refresh the page it is taking like this "http://localhost:8080/cisco/page" in the network section of the console

Comment: so you tell the app to go to a url that isnt in the app?

Comment: It is taking like that because of the html5Mode.